# How to reload an async belongsTo relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The model I have:

```
Post = DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.belongsTo('user',{ async: true })
});
```

but the url for the author is `/post/{id}/author` and it is passed via a key-value in the `links`-hash of the payload:

```
{
  post: {
    id: 1,
    links: {
      author: 'author'
    }
  }
}
```

The data is retreived by `post.get('author')` which calls the url `/posts/1/author`.
But now I want to reload the author data. When I try:

```
post.get('author').then(function(author) {
  author.reload();
});
```

the author is reloaded by calling `/users/{author_id}` instead of `/posts/1/author`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: That is the correct functionality, you are reloading the author not the post, so it will reload just the author, however the correct record will be reloaded, if you are passing the values correctly for the relationships and you have the relationships correctly setup it will update the author automatically, even if you don't call `/post/1/author`